# Using RealmSearchViewController with a UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm developing my first app in swift, which has a table that shows data stored using Realm. I've managed to add stuff to the Realm and show it in a table. Afterwards I wanted to add search capability and stumbled upon these two guides: http://www.raywenderlich.com/81615/introduction-to-realm and https://realm.io/news/building-an-ios-search-controller-in-swift/. I would like to use RealmSearchViewController, but I can’t seem to fit it to my setup. I tried using a UITableViewController embedded in a Navigation Controller, but I need a button at the bottom of the screen, where the user should tap to add an entry to the list. I tried using a tableFooterView with a button, but it can only stick to the bottom of the table and not the bottom of the screen. I also tried using a Tool Bar and a Tab Bar in the Navigation Controller, but it doesn’t show as the table takes up the whole screen.

What I would like to achieve is something like Airmail for iPhone, where there’s a Tab Bar at the bottom that is hidden when the user scrolls. Above the Tab Bar I’d like a table with content from the Realm, and then a Search Bar, which is directly below the Navigation Bar. I’d like to use RealmSearchViewController as it makes searching a lot easier, but how can I adapt it to be used with a Table View and not a Table View Controller?

Any other suggestions as to how I can achieve the same functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to create a parent view controller that arranges the the view of `RealmSearchViewController` so that it doesn't cover the entire screen, and then arrange a `UIButton` at the bottom.

You can do this in a Xib/Storyboard by arranging a view and a button with autolayout and then simply add the view from `RealmSearchViewController` as a subview to the view in this parent view controller.

Comment: Hi Adam. Sorry for taking so long but I've tried to understand how views and controllers work. I can't seem to understand how I can simply add a controller as a view. I'm guessing I don't fully understand your answer but I understand it as something like self.view.addSubview(RealmSearchViewController) which I don't understand how would work :) In my storyboard I have a UIView Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller. Inside the UIView Controller I have a Search Bar, a UIView and a Table View. But from looking at RealmSearchViewController.swift I'm guessing the Search Bar and the

Comment: Table View isn't needed as it's a part of RealmSearchViewController. But how can I then add the view below the navigation bar and above the view at the bottom? And how do I communicate values of variables to RealmSearchViewController? I'm guessing it would be smart to set entityName and searchPropertyKeyPath so how do I do that?